# Parsing array items json from codebehind to clientside jquery

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, json

I need to pass code behind array values to a jquery method using json.Please correct me if am wrong with this approach.created a webmethod returning the array elements.

```
C#:
[WebMethod]
        public static tagWords[] GetItems()
        {
            List<tagWords> drp = new List<tagWords>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=someDB;Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mySP", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID", 1));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Code", "Q22")); 
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@KeyValue", "1.4.9"));
                    con.Open();
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load(dr);
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            tagWords tagWords = new tagWords();
                            tagWords.text = dtRow["WORD"].ToString();
                            tagWords.weight = Convert.ToInt32(dtRow["first"]);
                            drp.Add(tagWords); 
                        }
                    }                
                }
            }
            return drp.ToArray();
        }
```

and now in aspx page written the following code,

Aspx:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function fncCloudItems() // place where json call happens
            {
                alert('fncCloudItems');
                 $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "JQCloud.aspx/GetItems",
                      data: "{}",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      dataType: "json",
                        success: function(output) {
                        var data = eval("(" + msg + ")");
                        functionOnSuccess(data);
                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                        alert(e);
                    }
                });
            }

            function functionOnSuccess(arrayOfElements) 
            {
                alert('functionOnSuccess');
                var obj = JSON.parse(arrayOfElements);
                alert(obj.count);
                alert(obj.length);
                var word_array=[];
                if (arrayOfElements != null && arrayOfElements != 'undefined') 
                {
                  for(i=0;i<arrayOfElements.length;i++)
                  {
                      var row = new Array();
                      row[0] = arrayOfElements[i].latitude;
                      row[1] = arrayOfElements[i].longitude;              
                      word_array.addRow(row);
                  }
                   $("#cloudDiv").jQCloud(word_array, 
                   {
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 350
                    }); 
                 }
            }       

            $(function () 
            {  
                alert('main call starts');
                    fncCloudItems();
                alert('main call ends');

            });
    </script>

Now the methods fires in the correct order starting from main call alert but its not            going to the functionOnSuccess method since something is wrong in the fncCloudItems method.
```

In the error alert am getting XML HTTPRequest Object.
    I have a breakpoint in the code behind method too (not hitting too).

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Check the console for the error. It will give you more detail to diagnose the problem.

Comment: var data = eval("(" + msg + ")"); is not required. the data is already in json format

Answer (score 0):

Since  data is coming as JSON there is no need to eval. Commenting out unwanted line.

```
      function fncCloudItems() // place where json call happens
        {
            alert('fncCloudItems');
             $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "JQCloud.aspx/GetItems",
                  data: "{}",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  dataType: "json",
                    success: function(output) {
                    //var data = eval("(" + msg + ")");
                    functionOnSuccess(output);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: No luck. Still the same happens.

Comment: Can you alert inside the success functon and see if ajax request passes? or fails?

Comment: The probably your ajax request is failing. You need to check the javascript console to see why it is failing. Possibly some server error.

Comment: checked with fiddler. ajax calls are making.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `ajax` function is ALREADY receiving data in a json format you dont need to do any further data parsing. Change your `success` handler to...

```
                success: function(output) {
                    var data = eval("(" + msg + ")");
                    functionOnSuccess(data);
                },
```

Then your `functionOnSuccess` doesn't need to do anything else apart from iterating through the array...

```
        function functionOnSuccess(arrayOfElements) 
        {
            var word_array=[];
            if (arrayOfElements != null && arrayOfElements != 'undefined') 
            {
              for(i=0;i<arrayOfElements.length;i++)
              {
                  var row = new Array();
                  row[0] = arrayOfElements[i].latitude;
                  row[1] = arrayOfElements[i].longitude;              
                  word_array.addRow(row);
              }
               $("#cloudDiv").jQCloud(word_array, 
               {
                width: 1000,
                height: 350
                }); 
             }
        }
```

#### Edit

You need to know what error is coming back from the server. You can do this using the browser debugging tool to inspect the response coming back from your server...all major browsers  come with a debugging tool (just press <kbd>F12</kbd>)

Also if you want to receive a proper error message in the `ajax` `error` handler change it to...

```
                error: function(x,s,e) {
                    alert(e);
                }
```

the parameters are:

- x: the whole response content received
- s: error message status
- e: error message

Comment: modified the code like you said.still it acts the same.

Comment: You need to inspect the response coming back from your server...I'll add an edit to my answer

Comment: for this code 
error: function(x,s,e) {
                    alert(e);
                } 
Alert throws undefined. Framework 2.0 am working